# Asus with gtx960m , fans maximum speed when at ubuntu 18/16 dual boot with windows 10

Tags: asus

I have a problem with my laptop fans that runs always at maximum speed even when nothing is running and the temperature is normal when on Ubuntu 18 or 16.
I think that the problem might be that some messages are sent to the fans with wrong information about the temperature telling them that the laptop is heating.
Can someone please tell me how to fix this? 
Is there an appropriate driver to install, or a fan controller that provides the right information about the temperature, because I don't want it to be me who controls the fans.
Thanks you !

Comment: Yrs, there are Nvidia drivers to install.

Comment: Yes I did install those, that is not the problem. The problem is with the fans.